# How to create a dictonary from a dataframe storing multiple dates as values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframe with columns containing dates (start and end date).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["key", "timestamp_1", "timestamp_2"],
    data=[
        (1, pd.to_datetime("2012-07-16 23:23:50"), pd.to_datetime("2012-07-18 23:23:50")),
        (2, pd.to_datetime("2012-08-16 02:23:50"), pd.to_datetime("2012-09-16 02:23:50")),
        (3, pd.to_datetime("2015-07-16 12:23:50"), pd.to_datetime("2015-08-16 12:23:50")),
        (4, pd.to_datetime("2018-08-16 20:23:50"), pd.to_datetime("2018-09-16 20:23:50")),
    ],
)
```

I tried this code and it basically does what I try to get as output, but the date values are getting lost:

```
df.groupby('key')['timestamp_1', 'timestamp_2'].apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).to_dict()


{1: [[1342481030000000000, 1342653830000000000]],
 2: [[1345083830000000000, 1347762230000000000]],
 3: [[1437049430000000000, 1439727830000000000]],
 4: [[1534451030000000000, 1537129430000000000]]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the conversion to [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) array with `x.values`, then to list. This sets the list items to be integers.

A workaround in pure pandas with [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('key')[['timestamp_1', 'timestamp_2']]
         .apply(lambda g: g.to_dict('split')['data']).to_dict()
      )
```

With a dictionary comprehension:

```
out = {k: g.to_dict('split')['data']
       for k, g in df.groupby('key')[['timestamp_1', 'timestamp_2']]}
```

Output (NB. replacing `2` by `1` in the original example to illustrate a group with more than one row):

```
{1: [[Timestamp('2012-07-16 23:23:50'), Timestamp('2012-07-18 23:23:50')],
     [Timestamp('2012-08-16 02:23:50'), Timestamp('2012-09-16 02:23:50')]],
 3: [[Timestamp('2015-07-16 12:23:50'), Timestamp('2015-08-16 12:23:50')]],
 4: [[Timestamp('2018-08-16 20:23:50'), Timestamp('2018-09-16 20:23:50')]]}
```

Alternatively, using strings:

```
out = (df.groupby('key')[['timestamp_1', 'timestamp_2']]
         .apply(lambda g: g.astype(str).values.tolist()).to_dict()
      )
```

Output:

```
{1: [['2012-07-16 23:23:50', '2012-07-18 23:23:50'],
     ['2012-08-16 02:23:50', '2012-09-16 02:23:50']],
 3: [['2015-07-16 12:23:50', '2015-08-16 12:23:50']],
 4: [['2018-08-16 20:23:50', '2018-09-16 20:23:50']]}
```

Or keeping numpy arrays as dictionary values:

```
out = {k: g.values for k, g in df.groupby('key')[['timestamp_1', 'timestamp_2']]}
```

Output:

```
{1: array([['2012-07-16T23:23:50.000000000', '2012-07-18T23:23:50.000000000'],
           ['2012-08-16T02:23:50.000000000', '2012-09-16T02:23:50.000000000']],
       dtype='datetime64[ns]'),
 3: array([['2015-07-16T12:23:50.000000000', '2015-08-16T12:23:50.000000000']],
       dtype='datetime64[ns]'),
 4: array([['2018-08-16T20:23:50.000000000', '2018-09-16T20:23:50.000000000']],
       dtype='datetime64[ns]')}
```